# Writing a job that can access office 365 email and migrate them elsewhere

Tags: email, sharepoint, office365

I need a little help understanding a task I have been given.

I started work on a 'SharePoint focused' team and we are trying to create a SharePoint portal that would house/manage all incoming mail to a specific company email address.

We have had a couple of issues setting up SharePoint to accept incoming mail, so have begun looking at other possible options.

1 option that was suggested was to 'write a job' that would read our mailbox server (on Office 365), and then find, pull and migrate/copy selected emails onto the sharepoint site.
(something else we are also interested in doing is seeing what info we can grab from these emails at this stage which we can use to create various mail objects in sharepoint with the mail metadata. Not sure what limitations there are to what can be accessed, if anything)

Is somebody able to explain a little more the type of process or work that is required to do this (access Office 365 mail via some API which we can create a timed job for), and any experience or advice around it? Where would I start looking or how would I start implementing it, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: I've come across this link, which Im going to investigate further. Will update if it answers my questions... 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations

Answer (score 0):

You combine couple of things together. SP can read incoming emails through locally installed and configured SMTP server. You can then setup document library or list to store them or create event listener to handle incoming emails completely by your own.

But both cases (OOTB functionality or event receiver) rely on local SMTP. If you want process emails from other server like Exchange Online you must either forward these emails to local SMTP server installed beside SP or you must create your own code. It can be SP job or any other type like windows service or console application executed by windows schedule, ... calling Exchange online API (designed specially for Exchange online) or MAPI or POP3 (generic using libraries) to get emails and calling SP API (CSOM, REST API) to store emails.